# Real Time TrafficSpeed info from DynamicSpeedInfo Tag

Tags: mapping, real-time, here-api

does anyone know, how can i get again according to gps daten(lon,lat) the trafficSpeed data in the DynamicSpeedInfo from here map.
3 Months ago it was enough to write this URL:http://route.st.nlp.nokia.com/routing/6.2/getlinkinfo.json?waypoint=48.78388,9.17932&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg
 The Url is no more functional.

but now i couldn't get the same Information with this:
https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/getlinkinfo.json?app_id=K0VaGAJa47ncpNYZzPTg&app_code=Fh0hkL6zUv7SKjr7U3XXCA&linkAttributes=dynamicSpeedInfo&waypoint=geo!49.0210,8.4310&time=now

if anyone help me, i will be glad.Thanks.What i need is below:

{"Response":{"MetaInfo":{"MapVersion":"2015Q4","ModuleVersion":"0.2","InterfaceVersion":"4.2","Timestamp":"2016-07-15T07:22:08.892Z"},"Link":[{"_type":"PrivateTransportLinkType","LinkId":"-52889551","Shape":["48.7840385,9.1789398","48.7838593,9.1793499"],"SpeedLimit":13.89,"DynamicSpeedInfo":{"TrafficSpeed":7.5,"TrafficTime":4.8,"BaseSpeed":13.89,"BaseTime":2.6},"Address":{"Label":"Arnulf-Klett-Platz, Schillerstraße","Country":"DE","State":"Baden-Württemberg","County":"Stuttgart","City":"Stuttgart","District":"Mitte","Street":"Arnulf-Klett-Platz, Schillerstraße"}}]}}

Comment: Router 6.2 is deprecated hence the urls wont be accessible anymore. In 7.2 getLinkInfo is also in Beta Phase, as mentioned in Migration guide it is recommended to use PDE (Platform Data Extension ) API to retrieve link Attributes. (https://developer.here.com/platform-extensions/documentation/platform-data/topics/quick-start.html) For traffic data you might have to use Traffic API to get JF and then calculate the traffic Speed (https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/rest/traffic/traffic-flow-proximity)

Comment: Do you know and sure about that, speedlimit= 70.8333359m/s in German Motrway, which has no speed limit.

Answer (score 0):

To get real-time traffic flow data e.g. speed for your 48.78388,9.17932 send please request to HERE Traffic API:

https://traffic.api.here.com/traffic/6.2/flow.json?corridor=48.78387%2C9.17933%3B48.78407%2C9.17893%3B1&app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&app_code=YOUR_APP_CODE

For the request above you need to have at least two waypoints. If you don't know a second waypoint then you can get it from HERE Fleet Telematics API to send follow request:

https://fleet.api.here.com/2/calculateroute.json?routeMatch=1&mode=fastest;car;traffic:disabled&app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&app_code=YOUR_APP_CODE&waypoint0=48.78388,9.17932&attributes=ROAD_GEOM_FCn(*)

In the response of above request under ROAD_GEOM_FCN you can get the link road geometry ([10^-5 degree WGS84] along the polyline. Comma separated. Each value is relative to the previous.):

> LAT: "4878387,20"
>
> LON: "917933,-40"

Then the first coordinate is 48.78387, 9.17933

second is:

> (4878387 + 20) / 100000 = 48.78407
>
> (917933 + (-40)) / 100000 = 9.17893

As you can see these coordinates were used in the Traffic API request.

[Traffic API example/documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/rest/traffic/flow-using-corridor)

[Fleet API example/documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/route-match/dev_guide/topics/quick-start-gps-trace-route.html)